# Handle multiple keypresses at once in Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, keypress, python-turtle

I've got a (hopefully) simple question. I want to script something, that lets two users move their python turtles with keypresses.
My script part:

```
#Forward
onkeypress(lambda:turtle1.forward(1),"Up")
onkeypress(lambda:turtle2.forward(1),"w")
#Backward
onkeypress(lambda:turtle1.forward(-1),"Down")
onkeypress(lambda:turtle2.forward(-1),"s")
listen()
```

If I do this, one turtle stops moving, when the other one starts. So "listen" does only listen for one keypress at once.

What to do if I want to handle two key inputs at once?

Comment: For this to work, you'd need a press and a release method. I don't find a release (for keys!) in the documentation, so I presume it doesn't work.

Comment: @deets Thank you for the idea. I'll search something like that now. If there's a way, it should work..

Comment: There's onkeyrelease. I think I can do something with that. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind several key presses together in turtle graphics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879608/how-to-bind-several-key-presses-together-in-turtle-graphics)