# Python 3 Turtle - Hold 2 keys

Tags: python

So I have a turtle that moves left when 'a' is pressed.

```
def turtle_left():
    turtle.forward(-1)

turtle.listen()
turtle.onkeypress(turtle_left, 'a')
```

However, if I wanted another movement, for example pressing 'w' makes it move up, then it stops the turtle moving left.
So what I'm asking is, can I have 2 keys being held at once to move the turtle, if possible I'd like to keep it in the turtle library - but maybe there is another key library that can help with this better.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that without using any external library. I think this post is very similar to the given below.

[How to bind several key presses together in turtle graphics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879608/how-to-bind-several-key-presses-together-in-turtle-graphics)

You can make an array of events and then process it on the basis of total events in the list.

Comment: Thank you, I used the test code and that seems to work. I'll edit that to fit with my code :)

Comment: It does indeed look similar to the question you linked to. In which case you should flag this as a duplicate of that one, rather than simply post a link to another question as an answer.