# What does turtle.tracer() do?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am currently learning about the `turtle` module in Python. So I read the function of [tracer()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.tracer) in this link, but I haven't understood what does **n-th regular screen update** actually means. If for example, I set `screen.tracer(0)` or `screen.tracer(2, 100)` what do they actually do?

Answer (score 6):

> The turtle was originally a small programmable physical robot that
> carried a pen and could ***trace*** its path as it moved.

From https://compform.net/turtles

Generally, the computer can draw graphics instantaneously.  Displaying every drawing update on the screen, and slowing down these updates, so we can see them, is *tracing* in turtle graphics.

The `tracer()` function turns automatic screen updates *on* or *off* -- *on* by default -- and also sets the `update()` delay.  In Python 2, the first argument to `tracer()` is boolean, `True` to have automatic screen updates on, `False` to turn them off.  You can still use `tracer()` this way in Python 3, and it's the way I most commonly use it.

In Python 3, the first argument, `n`, is a number.  If `n` is 0 (zero), automatic screen updates are off. If `n` is 1 (one), the default, automatic screen updates will happen.  This matches the Python 2 model.  When automatic updates are off, *you* need to *explicitly* call `update()` when you want the screen to reflect the current state of the drawing.

But in Python 3, if `n` is greater than 1 (one), then only every *nth* automatic screen update will occur.  If `n` is 2, only every other screen update will actually happen.  However, there's a glitch:

As I discuss in my [`tracer()` rules of thumb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62548843/5771269), some Python turtle graphics operations force an `update()` regardless of `tracer()` settings.  Due to this, and other turtle underpinnings, calculating the proper *nth* to set `n`, is error prone.  So my recommendation is to stick with the Python 2 model, and ignore this feature.

Finally, the second, `delay`,  argument to `tracer()`, is the time delay added after an `update()` to allow users to see the change, before something else gets updated.  The default value for this is 10 milliseconds, which is fairly short. This is similar to `turtle.speed()`, but affects everything, not just an individual turtle.