# Can you turn off tracer for TurtleScreen embedded in tkinter window?

Tags: tkinter, canvas, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have a fully functioning game in turtle. I moved it to a tkinter window and it works similar to before, but `screen.tracer(0)` does not seem to do anything (meaning it does not stop screen updates as expected). Also, `screen.addshape("shape")` doesn't seem to work either if anyone has an idea about that. I'm wondering if both methods don't actually work when the screen is embedded in a tkinter canvas. The rest of the methods, such as `screen.listen()` work as expected.

Here is some example code where I tried to get this to work, but the tracer clearly stays on since the turtle continues to draw on the screen when `"Up"` is pressed:

```
from turtle import TurtleScreen, RawTurtle
from tkinter import *


def go():
    turtle.forward(20)


window = Tk()
canvas = Canvas()
canvas.pack()
screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
turtle = RawTurtle(canvas)

screen.tracer(0)

screen.listen()
screen.onkey(fun=go, key="Up")

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does turtle.tracer() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62613041/what-does-turtle-tracer-do)

Comment: There is a duplicate to your question, and a great explanation of `turtle.tracer` its arguments, recommended uses, quircks and python 3 pitfalls [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62613041/what-does-turtle-tracer-do). `penup` and `pendown` work as intended.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Unfortunately, no. That explains very well what `turtle.tracer(0)` does, setting updates to False, but it doesn't explain why tkinter would be affecting this. In the case above, `screen.tracer(0)` should be making it so the screen does not update until `screen.update()` is called. But it continues to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you initialized your `RawTurtle()` with a `Canvas` instead of a `TurtleScreen`.  If we instead do `turtle = RawTurtle(screen)` everything works the same as *standalone* turtle:

```
from turtle import TurtleScreen, RawTurtle
from tkinter import *

def go():
    turtle.forward(20)

window = Tk()
canvas = Canvas()
canvas.pack()

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
turtle = RawTurtle(screen)

screen.tracer(0)

screen.onkey(fun=go, key="Up")
screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```

If you now add `screen.update()` as the last line of the `go()` event handler, the arrow will move and leave a trailing line.

Comment: Thank you so much! That resolved the issue.