# In Python turtle, with tracer off, is there a way to update the screen without using screen.update()?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm new to programming in Python.  About three weeks ago I finished a Tetris clone using the turtle module to test my skills. I was under the impression that when I turned off the animation tracer, I had to manually update the window with the `update()` method. Yesterday, while coding a snake clone with the turtle module, I had to explain to a friend why I was manually updating the screen. For proof, I opened Tetris and commented out the `update()` methods to show that the game would not work. To my surprise, it actually worked and I can't get my head around how it did as even my snake code would not work without the `update()` method.

Here is a part of the main loop of the Tetris code:

```
while not game_over:

if not current_piece.does_piece_fit(starting_row + 2, starting_column, current_piece.current_piece):
    game_over = True
wn.update()
movement()
marco.update_grid()
marco_next.show_next_piece(next_piece)
show_score()
current_piece.proyeccion()
marco_next.show_text(x_text_next_piece, y_text_next_piece, "Next Piece:", normal_style)
marco_next.show_text(x_text_hold, y_text_hold, "Hold:", normal_style)
show_instructions(x_text_instructions, y_text_instructions, instructions_text, smaller_style)

if holding:
    marco_hold.show_hold_piece(hold_piece)
```

If the `wn.update()` line is commented out, it shouldn't work, but somehow it does. The code is a bit lengthy and I'm new on this site so I don't know if posting it entirely might be considered bad or rude on my part. Thanks for reading this, sorry for the bad english and messy code.

Comment: create minimal working example with this problem. Show how you turn off tracing. As I remeber you can turn off totally or set how often it redraws screen so it may still works without `update()`. Or maybe there are some functions with may force turtle to redraw screen. For example `update_grid()`

Answer (score 1):

Some turtle commands call `update()` independent of you calling it.  Some like `end_fill()` do it directly, some like `dot()` do it indirectly due to other methods they invoke:

```
from turtle import *

tracer(False)

dot(100)  # change 'dot' to 'forward' and run again

done()
```

If you run the above, you'll get a dot despite the `tracer(False)` call.  If you change the `dot` to `forward` you'll get a blank screen unless you comment out the call to `tracer`.

My rules of thumb for `update()` are:

- don't assume that anyone will call it for you
- don't assume that you are the only one calling it

This is not just true for Python turtle.  My advice, put back your `update()` calls where you believe you need them, otherwise a future update of turtle might break your code.