# How to get multiple keybindings to work simultaniously in turtle graphics?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, pong, python-turtle

I am making a game in python called pong.

Can I get 2 different turtles in turtle graphics to respond simultaneously to keybindings?

Here is the code:

```
import turtle


class paddle(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self, x_cord, keybindings):
        super().__init__("square")

        self.color("white")
        self.penup()
        self.goto(x_cord, 0)
        self.turtlesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1, outline=1)
        self.screen = turtle.Screen()
        self.screen.bgcolor("black")
        self.screen.tracer(0)
        self.screen.listen()
        self.screen.update()

        def up():
            self.goto(self.xcor(), self.ycor() + 10)
            self.screen.update()

        def down():
            self.goto(self.xcor(), self.ycor() - 10)
            self.screen.update()

        self.screen.onkey(up, keybindings[0])
        self.screen.onkey(down, keybindings[1])


paddle_1 = paddle(-350, ["Up", "Down"])
paddle_2 = paddle(350, ["w", "s"])

food.screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was once a problem I struggled with for a long time, and came to the conclusion that it's not possible *(please prove me wrong, as I'm interested in the solution if there is one)*.

I've analyzed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47894123/13552470) great answer that explains how to bind two arrow keys for diagonal movement, but it only works one step at a time, just like how your code allows for simultaneous movement of the turtles as long as making them move one step at a time.

Anyways, that situation pushed me further into embracing the versatile [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/docs/) python package.