# how to solve keybinding python turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, key-bindings, python-turtle

i am new in python i am trying to make a ping pong game but i cant move my turtle objects with
key bindings
there is my code
import turtle

```
# inishialize screen
the_ping_pong_windows = turtle.Screen()
# set the screen title
the_ping_pong_windows.title("stage of ping pong")
# set the screen color
the_ping_pong_windows.bgcolor("black")
# set the widht and heigt of the window
the_ping_pong_windows.setup(width=1000, height=600)
# stops the window from updating automatically
the_ping_pong_windows.tracer(0)
# madrab 1
# create a turtle object (SHAPE) eli men 5laloh a2dar a3ml shakl el madrab eli ana 3ayzoh
madrab1 = turtle.Turtle()
# set the speed of the animation dih mi4 el sor3ah eli el mAdrab  dih el sor3ah eli beyrsem biha el turtle object
# el madrab kol ma ytharak 34an a2dar a4ofoh
madrab1.speed(0)
madrab1.shape("square")
# set the madrab's color
madrab1.color("red")
madrab1.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
madrab1.penup()
madrab1.goto(-420, 0)
# madrab 2
madrab2 = turtle.Turtle()
madrab2.speed(0)
madrab2.shape("square")
madrab2.color("blue")
madrab2.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
madrab2.penup()
madrab2.goto(420, 0)
# ball
ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.shape("circle")
ball.color("white")
ball.penup()
ball.goto(0, 0)


# functions
def madrab1_up():
    y = madrab1.ycor()
    y += 20
    madrab1.sety(y)

def madrab1_down():
    y = madrab1.ycor()
    y -= 20
    madrab1.sety(y)


def madrab2_up():
    y = madrab2.ycor()
    y += 22
    madrab2.sety(y)

def madrab2_down():
    y = madrab2.ycor()
    y -= 20
    madrab1.sety(y)


# keyboard binding
the_ping_pong_windows.listen()
the_ping_pong_windows.onkeypress(madrab1_up,"w")
the_ping_pong_windows.onkeypress(madrab1_down,"g")
the_ping_pong_windows.onkeypress(madrab2_up,"s")
the_ping_pong_windows.onkeypress(madrab1_down,"Up")
the_ping_pong_windows.update()
the_ping_pong_windows.exitonclick()
```

i do not know how to solve this problem
when i click "w" for example the shape dint move
and i am not getting any error
please if someone have a way to solve this problem tell me
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key listeners are set up correctly, but there's no rendering loop. Calling `tracer(0)` disables turtle's internal update loop, and it's on you to reimplement manually. `.update()` is called once in your code, but never again once the key handlers start firing.

Try calling `.update()` inside a `ontimer` cycle like:

```py
# ...

def tick():
    the_ping_pong_windows.ontimer(tick, 1000 // 30)

    # handle movement and drawing here

    the_ping_pong_windows.update()

tick()
the_ping_pong_windows.exitonclick()
```

Since you're applying position changes in the handler, movement won't be smooth. See [How to bind several key presses together in turtle graphics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879608/how-to-bind-several-key-presses-together-in-turtle-graphics/70979967#70979967) for an improved design that tracks key presses/releases in handlers and only applies movement during a `tick` call.