# Two-player Python Turtle game with actions bound to WASD and arrow keys

Tags: python, function, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

What I want to do is creating two players and their navigation with WASD and the arrows. For one player I can create it, and I could copy paste it, but I want another solution which is shorter.

For one player the navigation looks like this:
(before this I created a turtle with the name t)

```
def up():
    y = t.ycor()
    y += 5
    t.sety(y)

def down():
    y = t.ycor()
    y -= 5
    t.sety(y)

def left():
    x = t.xcor()
    x -= 5
    t.setx(x)

def right():
    x = t.xcor()
    x += 5
    t.setx(x)

wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(up, "Up")
wn.onkeypress(down, "Down")
wn.onkeypress(left, "Left")
wn.onkeypress(right, "Right")`
```

In my first attempt I added 'mode' to it:
(I only tested it for going up with the 'player')
(Here I created two turtles: p1 and p2)

```
def up(mode="p1"):
    if mode == "p1":
        y = p1.ycor()
        y += 5
        p1.sety(y)
    elif mode == "p2":
        y = p2.ycor()
        y += 5
        p2.sety(y)

wn.listen()
fel("p2")
wn.onkeypress(up, 'Up')
fel("p1")
wn.onkeypress(up, "w")`
```

It only works if I change p1 in def line to p2.

Can I change the players like this? Is there any other possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

In general, avoid the ["boolean parameter antipattern"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147977/is-it-wrong-to-use-a-boolean-parameter-to-determine-behavior). If a function has a flag that switches between two disjoint branches (a string that can only have two values is effectively a flag boolean), generally make it into two functions and remove the `if`, or pass a more meaningful parameter like a turtle to the function, if that's the only difference between the two branches. For example:

```py
def up(t):
    y = t.ycor()
    y += 5
    t.sety(y)
```

Then bind this twice:

```py
wn.onkeypress(lambda: up(p), 'Up')
wn.onkeypress(lambda: up(p2), 'w')
```

You can shorten the function to:

```py
def up(t):
    t.sety(t.ycor() + 5)
```

at which point it can be a lambda and be used directly in the `onkeypress` call.

Here's an example of how I'd set this up by modifying [this realtime turtle boilerplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879608/how-to-bind-several-key-presses-together-in-turtle-graphics/70979967#70979967) to support a second player, `t2`, which has actions bound to the WASD keys.

```py
import turtle

def tick():
    for action in keys_pressed:
        actions[action]()

    turtle.update()
    win.ontimer(tick, frame_delay_ms)

t = turtle.Turtle()
t2 = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.tracer(0)
frame_delay_ms = 1000 // 30
step_speed = 10

actions = dict(
    Up=lambda: t.sety(t.ycor() + step_speed),
    Left=lambda: t.setx(t.xcor() - step_speed),
    Down=lambda: t.sety(t.ycor() - step_speed),
    Right=lambda: t.setx(t.xcor() + step_speed),

    w=lambda: t2.sety(t2.ycor() + step_speed),
    a=lambda: t2.setx(t2.xcor() - step_speed),
    s=lambda: t2.sety(t2.ycor() - step_speed),
    d=lambda: t2.setx(t2.xcor() + step_speed),
)
win = turtle.Screen()
keys_pressed = set()

def bind(key):
    win.onkeypress(lambda: keys_pressed.add(key), key)
    win.onkeyrelease(lambda: keys_pressed.remove(key), key)

for key in actions:
    bind(key)

win.listen()
tick()
win.exitonclick()
```

We could remove a little bit of repetition (`t` and `t2`, as well as the movement lambdas) by abstracting the keys per player to lists, but this feels a bit premature to me since the lists will iterate only 2 times and we know that there will never be a third player so the benefits of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)ing up the code are negligible at this stage in development. The [AHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#AHA) principle (avoid hasty abstractions) takes precedence.

If movement becomes more complicated, then I'd convert those lambdas back to normal functions as shown at the top of this answer. Here's equivalent code as the above example, but with the functions abstracted out and ready for extension:

```py
def up(t):
    t.sety(t.ycor() + step_speed)

def left(t):
    t.setx(t.xcor() - step_speed)

def down(t):
    t.sety(t.ycor() - step_speed)

def right(t):
    t.setx(t.xcor() + step_speed)

actions = dict(
    Up=lambda: up(t),
    Left=lambda: left(t),
    Down=lambda: down(t),
    Right=lambda: right(t),

    w=lambda: up(t2),
    a=lambda: left(t2),
    s=lambda: down(t2),
    d=lambda: right(t2),
)
```

Going a step further, another possible abstraction opportunity is using a single function for movement and passing in the `delta_x`, `delta_y` parameters to specify direction offsets (`+` / `-` symbols), which are the only difference between these 4 functions. This is pretty clearly premature here, but if movement became more complex and involved multiple steps repeated in each of these functions, breaking the logic out and parameterizing offsets is a common factoring opportunity.

Hopefully, it's apparent that the design from the original boilerplate already uses data structures like the `actions` table to avoid repetition and keep the code free of branching.

Another side point from the original code is that `keys_pressed` ensures smooth movement and avoids OS-specific keyboard retriggering behavior. All movement should be processed only in the update loop, not in event handlers.