# How would I make the turtle player move animation smooth instead of the current way it jumps?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Trying to make the player move glide across the screen on key presses instead of jumping across.

```
import turtle

scrn = turtle.Screen()
scrn.title("Falling Skies Game")
scrn.setup(width=800, height=600)
scrn.bgcolor("sky blue")

# Adding the player
player = turtle.Turtle()
player.speed(0)
player.shape("square")
player.color("white")
player.penup()  
player.goto(0,-250)

def playerleft():
    player.setheading(180)
    player.forward(25)

def playerright():
    player.setheading(0)
    player.forward(25)

scrn.listen()       
scrn.onkeypress(playerleft, 'Left')
scrn.onkeypress(playerright, 'Right')

scrn.mainloop()
```

Able to make the player move but it jumps across the screen on keypress but I need it to glide across.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `player.forward(25)` with a loop that executes `player.forward(1)` 25 times, with perhaps a short sleep inserted as well?

Comment: `player.speed(0)` is fastest. But I'd use `tracer(0)` for any real-time turtle apps. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879608/how-to-bind-several-key-presses-together-in-turtle-graphics/70979967#70979967), otherwise you won't be able to control the animation speed effectively, and you won't be able to move multiple turtles at once. So not using `tracer(0)` may be a non-starter even if you get this working by messing with `speed()`. What game are you creating, for context?

Comment: @Malcolm Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think this will be a good solution for realtime turtle graphics. It's annoying to code and won't be a consistent framerate between machines. OP will not be able to move multiple turtles easily, which is almost certainly the next thing they'll be trying to do in their game. `tracer()` and `ontimer()` is a better fundamental solution.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question as a proper sentence to make it more clear?

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is this line:

```
player.speed(0)
```

---

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.speed) (emphasis added):

> `turtle.speed(speed=None)`
>
> Parameters: `speed` – an integer in the range
> `0..10` or a speedstring (see below)
>
> Set the turtle’s speed to an integer value in the range `0..10`. If no
> argument is given, return current speed.
>
> If input is a number greater than 10 or smaller than 0.5, speed is set
> to 0. Speedstrings are mapped to speedvalues as follows:
>
> “fastest”: 0
>
> “fast”: 10
>
> “normal”: 6
>
> “slow”: 3
>
> “slowest”: 1
>
> Speeds from 1 to 10 enforce increasingly faster animation of line
> drawing and turtle turning.
>
> **Attention: speed = 0 means that no animation takes place. forward/back**
> **makes turtle jump and likewise left/right make the turtle turn**
> **instantly.**