# Python turtle moving using keyboard (code noob)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

So, I need to make a code where turtle move when you press w,a,s,d, without importing keyboard in python.

```
from turtle import *
x=100
z=90
v=input()
while True:
    if v == 'w':
        forward(x)    
    if v == 's':
        backward(x)
    if v == 'd':
        right(z)
    if v == 'a':
        left(z)
```

there is the code.

The problem is, when i press any of these buttons turtle moves infinitely, without stopping. I have no idea how to fix this, and im kinda sure its easy to fix. It has to be infinite, so "while" is required. Also dont mind my grammar,I think I did some grammar mistakes here. Code shouldn't be fully rewritten.

Comment: `input` should be in the loop too

Comment: Are you looking to use smooth, continuous movement like a game? If so, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879608/how-to-bind-several-key-presses-together-in-turtle-graphics/70979967#70979967). It's a bit unusual to use `input()` since the user will have to press one direction key, then Enter to make a single step. What do you mean by "importing keyboard"? To use turtle's `screen.onkey` requires no import beyond the one you have (but avoid wildcard imports in favor of `from turtle import Screen, Turtle` to avoid many gotchas that can occur).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the issue of the turtle moving infinitely without stopping, you need to continuously update the value of `v` inside the while loop to capture the user input repeatedly.

Here's the modified code:

```
from turtle import *

x = 100
z = 90

while True:
    v = input("Enter a command (w, a, s, d): ")
    if v == 'w':
        forward(x)
    elif v == 's':
        backward(x)
    elif v == 'd':
        right(z)
    elif v == 'a':
        left(z)
    else:
        print("Invalid command. Please enter w, a, s, or d.")
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
while True:
    screen.onkey(forward, "w")
    screen.onkey(backward, "s")
    screen.onkey(right, "d")   
    screen.onkey(left, "a")    
    screen.listen()
```

do this. put the input part in the loop.

Comment: `TypeError: TurtleScreen.onkey() missing 1 required positional argument: 'key'`